# Phaser Game Keyboard .addKey Enter or Mobile Touch

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, 2d-games

How to add both options like Enter or Mobile touch to start

```
this.enter = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.ENTER);
```

Or

```
this.enter = this.input.on('pointerdown', this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want the result to be, you could:

create one function, that handles both events:

```
function doAction(){
   alert('action')
}
```

and then reference the same function in the event listeners, of both actions:

```
this.enter = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.ENTER); 
this.enter.on('down', doAction);

// ... AND

this.input.on('pointerdown', doAction);
```

**Update:**
If you want to, check what device type the app is being run, you could use the information of `this.sys.game.device.os` ([link to documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Device.html#.OS__anchor) )

Comment: can you check this one please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500231/what-do-i-need-to-change-for-use-on-a-mobile-cell-phone-browser-to-make-the-play

Comment: @mdsami did my answer helpt your problem? if so accept it, if not explain what is missing or where you need help. to ask me to look at a different question without responding to the current one is a bit odd.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for bit late accepted.  just stuck on a new problem