# What do I need to change for use on a mobile cell phone browser to make the player automatically jump when the screen touch

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, 2d-games

What do I need to change for use on a mobile cell phone browser to make the player automatically run to the right and jump when the screen is tapped? I've searched for ages but can't find the answer and am trying to learn

here is the code

```
update(time, delta) {
    moveBackgroundPlatform(this.mountainGroup, this.mountainWidth, 'mountains', 0.5);
    moveBackgroundPlatform(this.plateauGroup, this.plateauWidth, 'plateau', 1.5);
    moveBackgroundPlatform(this.groundGroup, this.groundWidth, 'ground', 4);

    if (this.health <= 0) {
        const myUrl = `${fetchScoreData.apiUrl + fetchScoreData.apiKey}/scores`;

        fetchScoreData.postScores(myUrl, { user: gameState.playerName, score: gameState.score });

        this.gameTheme.stop();
        this.scene.stop();
        this.scene.start('GameOver');
    }

    if (this.missileScore >= 1) {
        this.health += 1;
        this.missileScore -= 1;
    }

    this.player.anims.play('run', true);
    this.birdGroup.children.iterate((child) => {
        child.anims.play('fly', true);
    });

    this.missileGroup.children.iterate((child) => {
        child.x -= 5;
    });

    this.timer += delta;
    if (this.timer >= 5000) {
        this.createMissile(415, 'missile');
        this.timer = 0;
    }

    this.secondTimer += delta;
    if (this.secondTimer >= 7000) {
        this.createMissile(300, 'missile2');
        this.secondTimer = 0;
    }

    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.cursors.up)) {

        //this.input.on('pointerdown',  this.jump, this);
        console.log(' up preess');
        if (this.player.body.touching.down || (this.jump < this.jumpTimes && (this.jump > 0))) {
            this.player.setVelocityY(-400);
            this.jumpSound.play();

            if ((this.player.body.touching.down)) {
                this.jump = 0;
            }
            this.jump += 1;
        }
    }

    if (!this.player.body.touching.down) {
        this.player.anims.play('jump', true);
    }

    if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
        if (!this.player.body.touching.down) {
            this.player.setGravityY(1300);
        }
    }

    if (this.player.body.touching.down) {
        this.player.setGravityY(800);
    }
}
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems? making the player run , or jumping or...? please specify your problem a bit more. What have you tried?

Comment: p.s: here is the Stackoverflow guide on questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this helps you get answers faster.

Comment: thanks winner_joiner i have tried ````  this.input.on('pointer down', this.jump, this) ``` but Won't Work

Comment: it has to be inside the the `create` method. I will try to create or find a small working demo.

Comment: I found an example, it is abit long, but you can see the `on` pointer event on the line 100. https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-animation-from-sprite-sheet#, should work in mobile

Comment: btw.: the phaser page has alot of examples to many topics. here you can find alot of good examples. https://phaser.io/examples on that page and in the documentation, I learned most of what I know about phaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way's to solve this, I'm no professional, but I would add a pointer event listener in the `create` method of the scene:

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', jump, this);
```

and the `jump` method, that holds all the jump logic:

```
jump(){
    if (this.player.body.touching.down || (this.jump < this.jumpTimes && (this.jump > 0))) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-400);
        this.jumpSound.play();

        if ((this.player.body.touching.down)) {
            this.jump = 0;
        }
        this.jump += 1;
    }
}
```

this `jump`method you could call in the `update` function t prevent duplication of code.

```
update(time, delta) {
    ...
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.cursors.up)) {
        jump();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```